# How do I cause an attempt to uninstall my Windows service to fail if another service has a dependency on it?

Tags: .net, windows-services, wix, windows-installer, dependency-management

I have a Windows service (written in .NET) for which I built an installer using WiX 3.7. It serves an infrastructure role, and anyone can write another Windows Service that uses it. Since my service is required to run when any other such services uses it, the installers of other services define my service as their "Service Dependency" during installation.

Unfortunately, Windows seems to allow removing a Windows service even when other services depend on it. I'd like to make my installer give an error and fail to uninstall my service when any other dependent service is still installed on that machine.

I don't know what other services will be built on top of mine, so I can't hard-code any checks.

Is there a way to do this with WiX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom action and fail the uninstall if there are other services using your service.

`OpenSCManager` + `EnumServicesStatusEx` (to find all services) + `OpenService` + `QueryServerConfig`(to find the dependencies)

The custom action should set a WiX variable (for example "SERVICE_IS_USED") and then you test it with a Condition element:

```
  <Condition Message ="Stop using me first!">
    SERVICE_IS_USED = "0"
  </Condition>
```

(In practise, I'd add additional conditions so this only applies during uninstall, and I'd seriously consider allowing a FORCE option to allow the uninstall even if the service *is* in use.

I would recommend writing the custom action in C or C++ rather than .Net - the bootstrapping process for running custom actions in .Net scares me.

If you don't already have a boostrapper for your installer to install dependencies like the .Net framework and C runtime libraries, I would go further and recommend writing the custom action in C in way which doesn't use the C runtime library (just Windows API calls).

P.S. Incidentally, I don't think this is really related to .Net - it's much more windows-services, wix, and windows-installer

Comment: I imagined there would be some built-in way to perform the verification, as it seems like a common requirement when uninstalling services. I guess it is considerable more uncommon than I originally thought, so a custom action is indeed the way to go here. Thanks for the pointers!